# Casting using int() turns 16.0 to 15

Tags: python, casting, int

So I have a weird problem when trying to cast a float number to an integer. My code currently looks like this:

```
from math import gcd 
def dostuff(n,m):
    L = np.sqrt(n**2+m**2+n*m)
    dR = gcd(2*m+n,2*n+m)
    atoms=4*L**2/dR
    print(atoms)
    atoms = int(atoms)
    print(atoms)
```

When I run this code with n=4 and m=4, the first print returns 16.0, while the second print returns 15. What is the reason for this, and is there anything I can do to make the second one return 16 instead?

Comment: Your number is just a tiny fraction below an actual `16.0`, just enough so it gets rounded out in printing but makes a difference when truncating. You can never expect floats to be precise. *Rounding* the number would be an answer to the immediate question, but whether that's generally the right answer for your algorithm we don't know.

Comment: have check it,as I got `15.99999999998` and `15` which is expected,converting the float to int will give floor of the number

Comment: This is a basic floating point precision issue. The core of it is that `np.sqrt(48)**2` is not equal to `48`, it's very slightly smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried a round function?
round(atoms) it will round to the nearest integer 5.6 will be 6 and 5.4 will be 5
if you want to go up use ceil(atoms) otherwise floor(atoms). hope this helps you!